# Двойная итерация по словарю python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

В реализации парсера есть словарь:

```
areas = {
    'Краснодарский край': '1_11',
    'Ростовская обл': '1_12',
    'Ставропольский край': '1_13',
    'Московская обл': '1_1'
    }
```

Нужно пройтись по нему два раза. Сейчас реализовано двумя циклами, подстановкой значений в url, а ключей в другую функцию:

```
areas = {
    'Краснодарский край': '1_11',
    'Ростовская обл': '1_12',
    'Ставропольский край': '1_13',
    'Московская обл': '1_1'
    }
url = ''
for key_from, value_from in areas.items():
    url_from = f'https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"{value_from}","fromGeo":"{value_from}","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"'
    for key_to, value_to in areas.items():
        url = f'{url_from}{value_to}","toGeo":"{value_to}","rate":15%7D'
        print(url)
```

Уверен, есть более элегантное решение. Если подскажете, буду благодаре

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сокращенный вариант для демонстрации работы с комбинациями элементов коллекции:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

url_templ = 'https://api.ru/"from":{},"to":{}'

areas = {
    'Краснодарский край': '1_11',
    'Ростовская обл': '1_12',
    'Ставропольский край': '1_13',
    'Московская обл': '1_1'
    }

for url in starmap(url_templ.format, product(areas.values(), repeat=2)):
   print(url)
```

P.S. Немного смущает, что в вашей задаче пунткы `from` и `to` могут совпадать.

P.P.S. Если такое поведение не предусмотрено, то [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) можно заменить на [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: Мне как раз и нужно чтобы один раз `from` и `to` совпадали. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить сделать:

- Строка-шаблон для URL
- Работа только с значениями словаря

Пример:

```
areas = {
    'Краснодарский край': '1_11',
    'Ростовская обл': '1_12',
    'Ставропольский край': '1_13',
    'Московская обл': '1_1'
}

PATTERN_URL = 'https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"{value_from}","fromGeo":"{value_from}","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"{value_to}","toGeo":"{value_to}","rate":15%7D'

geos = areas.values()

for value_from in geos:
    for value_to in geos:
        url = PATTERN_URL.format(value_from=value_from, value_to=value_to)
        print(url)
```

Можно, конечно, сделать кое-что, что я бы не рекомендовал. Используя [product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) получите тот же результат как если бы использовался двойной цикл:

```
from itertools import product

...

for value_from, value_to in product(geos, repeat=2):
    url = PATTERN_URL.format(value_from=value_from, value_to=value_to)
    print(url)
```

Результат:

```
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_11","fromGeo":"1_11","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_11","toGeo":"1_11","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_11","fromGeo":"1_11","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_12","toGeo":"1_12","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_11","fromGeo":"1_11","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_13","toGeo":"1_13","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_11","fromGeo":"1_11","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_1","toGeo":"1_1","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_12","fromGeo":"1_12","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_11","toGeo":"1_11","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_12","fromGeo":"1_12","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_12","toGeo":"1_12","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_12","fromGeo":"1_12","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_13","toGeo":"1_13","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_12","fromGeo":"1_12","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_1","toGeo":"1_1","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_13","fromGeo":"1_13","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_11","toGeo":"1_11","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_13","fromGeo":"1_13","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_12","toGeo":"1_12","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_13","fromGeo":"1_13","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_13","toGeo":"1_13","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_13","fromGeo":"1_13","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_1","toGeo":"1_1","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_1","fromGeo":"1_1","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_11","toGeo":"1_11","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_1","fromGeo":"1_1","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_12","toGeo":"1_12","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_1","fromGeo":"1_1","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_13","toGeo":"1_13","rate":15%7D
https://loads.ati.su/#?filter=%7B"exactFromGeos":true,"exactToGeos":true,"extraParams":129,"from":"","fromGeo_tmp":"1_1","fromGeo":"1_1","to":"","toGeo_tmp":"1_1","toGeo":"1_1","rate":15%7D
```

Comment: К сожалению, мне нужны так же и ключи. Спарсить информацию по областям невозможно, только города, поэтому приходится брать области и края из словаря по ключам. Но ваше решение немного сократит код. Спасибо.

Comment: _я бы не рекомендовал_ почему, если не секрет?)

Comment: @EvgeniyK, тогда оставьте ключи и используйте двойной цикл, т.е. как у вас и сделано было

Comment: @mkkik, лично мне двойной цикл понятнее, чем `product`, увижу `product` в том же коде через неделю-две и точно задумаюсь что он делает. Но мне понравилось как вы использовали `starmap` с `url_templ.format` и `product`, выглядит очень просто :)